# simple way rather than to call a function repeatedly in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a function and some input element(s) will use that for a purpose.
i tried to make an array of them and pass to that function, but failed.

```
$("#txtFirst").change(function(){validateForm($(this));});
$("#txtLast").change(function(){validateForm($(this));});
$("#txtNick").change(function(){validateForm($(this));});
```

how to make it more simple, rather than use same format repeatedly?

Comment: `$("#txtFirst, #txtLast, #txtNick").change(function(){validateForm($(this));});`?

Comment: Can you add HTML too

Comment: @Tushar Thank You sir, it is works!

Comment: Welcome! Glad it helped, if you can add HTML, I think that can also be optimized

Comment: If all the inputs are in a form, `$('form').on('change', ':text', function() { validateForm($(this)); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target multiple elements in one selector :

```
$("#txtFirst, #txtLast, #txtNick").change(function(){validateForm($(this));});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#txtFirst, #txtLast, #txtNick").change(function(){validateForm($(this));});
```